# Automatically sort column by status

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

I am trying to automatically sort column E which is my status column (done, to do, in progress) so that when I change it to done, it drops down to the bottom of the list but maintains the priority by due date.

I tried to run some scripts but I'm a novice to the scripts. Any help and clarity will be greatly appreciated!

The spreadsheet can be found here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QQ8AEaCTlhwdog9tt_YqaU_eNc2TUbcU8v_YpG_ghBo/edit?usp=sharing

My current code is:

```
function onEdit(event){
  Logger.log('it ran');
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var editedCell = sheet.getActiveCell();

  var columnToSortBy = 2;
  var tableRange = "E2:F"; //range to be sorted

  if(editedCell.getColumn() == columnToSortBy){   
    var range = sheet.getRange(tableRange); 
    range.sort( { column : columnToSortBy, ascending: true } );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share the script you wrote to perform the desired action?

Comment: Look at onEdit onChange and also how to sort a spreadsheetApp range. If still wont work post the code in your question.

Comment: You've got the `onEdit()` function inside of the `myFunction()` function.  That won't work.